# What to do to disable button when using mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf

I just started using and learning mvvm. A `RelayCommand` I set on the ViewModel side does not disable the button on the view side. When I initially set `CanExecute` return false the button appears to be disabled and the keyboard is not getting focus. But the button doesn't get disabled when `CanExecute` returns false at runtime like below. Where could the error be?

```xml
<Button Content="Test" 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Width="60" 
        Height="50" 
        Command="{Binding Path=TestCommand}"/>
```

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using TestWpfApplication.Models;

namespace TestWpfApplication.ViewModels
{
    public class PersonView : ObservableObject
    {
        private bool canExecute=true;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChange;
        
        public bool _canExecute 
        { 
            get => canExecute; 
            set => SetProperty(ref canExecute,value); 
        } 
        
        private Person person;

        public Person Person
        {
            get => person;
            set => SetProperty(ref person, value);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public PersonView()
        {
                        person = new Person();
            Persons.Add(new Person() { Ad = "Fatih", Soyad = "Uyanık", Yas = 12 });
            Persons.Add(new Person() { Ad = "eymen", Soyad = "Uyanık", Yas = 4 });
            Persons.Add(new Person() { Ad = "Deneme1", Soyad = "Deneme1", Yas = 12 });
        }
        
                       private ICommand testCommand;
        public ICommand TestCommand => testCommand = new RelayCommand(Test, TestCanExecute);

        private int Sayac = 0;
        private bool TestCanExecute() => canExecute;
        private void Test()
        {
            canExecute = Sayac++<3;
                                }

    }
}
```

Comment: ICommand has an event called CanExecuteChanged.  This event has to fire in order for WPF to call the CanExecute method again.  RelayCommand has a public method NotifyCanExecuteChanged().  I think that's what you want to use if you want to avoid things like binding to IsEnabled on your button etc

Comment: Hello
I am trying to use it that way. But the button is not disabled at runtime. I actually wanted to use it this way without using IsEnable. However it didn't work for me. I think there is something I missed somewhere.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28343632/1136211 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1340302/1136211

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can easily bind the IsEnabled property of the button, and by setting that property to false the button will be disabled.

```
<Button Content="Test" Grid.Column="1" Width="60" Height="50" Command="{Binding Path=TestCommand}" IsEnabeled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}"/>
```

On the ViewModel

```
        bool isButtonEnabled;
    public bool IsButtonEnabled
    {
        get => isButtonEnabled;
        set => SetProperty(ref isButtonEnabled, value);
    }
```

Comment: Possible yes, but with the command binding everything is already at hand - when you use it. This is like jumping over the river when the bridge is just a step next to you ;o)